# Merge Files in a directory, with a newline appended each time

Tags: c#, file, io, streamwriter

I have a bunch of txt files in a directory which I want to merge into one file. At the end of each file I want to append a carriage return/ new line.

What is the best way to do this in c#?

Comment: What have you tried? Based on the tags on your question it looks like you are heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One-liner which is likely pretty lean on memory consumption:

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    targetFileName,
    Directory.GetFiles(srcFolder, "*.txt")
        .SelectMany(f=>
            File.ReadLines(f).Concat(new[] {Environment.NewLine})));
```

Hope you can live with the extra newline at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I won't write the code for you, but I'll point you in the right direction.

- Use the [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/) method to iterate through the files
- Use a [StreamReader](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader) to read the files in to a buffer appending a newline after each file.
- Use a [StreamWriter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter) to write the buffer back out to an output file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a declarative approach using [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) which works well for large directories because it streams the file names as it discovers them.

```
var lines = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*.txt")
            from line in File.ReadLines(file).Concat(new[]{Environment.NewLine})
            select line;
File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, lines);
```

Benefits of this approach:

- **Readable** and easy to understand
- **Parallelizable** if you have many files (> 10000):

  Just add `.AsParallel()` to the end of the first line. Memory usage will of course increase, but you'll get the job done much faster, especially for hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: +1 cos I've learned something new (`Directory.EnumerateFiles`)

Answer (score 0):

I do not write code for you either, but i have used the  following code to do this, i remember the files were named 1.txt, 2.txt etc. so i could loop through the whole folder

```
    private void merge()
    {
        string[] fullFile = new string[152];
        System.IO.StreamWriter data = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filepath);
        for (int i = 1; i < 152; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                string fullfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
                data.WriteLine(fullfile + "return\n");

            }
            catch { }
        }
        data.Close();

    }
```